# How to extract the data value from a UiPath QueueItem in Studio?

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-orchestrator, uipath-activity, uipath-api

I have added Itens to my UiPath queue but I can’t extract the data when I pull from the queue.

I can loop through the QueueItems and even set the transaction to SUCCESS but I can’t figure out how to get the data in the QueueItem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the call you are looking for is this:

```
QueueItem.SpecificContent("email").ToString
```

That assumes they key you are looking for in the [UiPath Queue](https://youtu.be/3X1BZ0pSSp0) is named 'email.'

### Read UiPath QueueItem Example

Here's a fairly descriptive image that shows the item on the queue, along with all of its name-value pairs, along with the code used in a UiPath Studio project. The output of running this [UiPath Robot](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Create-your-first-RPA-robot-to-UiPath-Orchestrator-tutorial) is in the lower left hand corner, so you can see how all of the pieces tie together.

[image]